# Tracking changes in textbox in scala js

Tags: scala.js

I've a text box in my html file and I want to detect whenever a user changes the value of it and determine its updated value also. html code for text box is :

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="0" onchange="Demo().change(id,value)">
```

and in my scala file, I've implemented a function 'change' as :

```
@JSExport
def change(id:String):Unit={
appendPar(document.body,"Text Box value is changed and the new value is : "+document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value"))
}
```

But it is not working in my case. What am I doing wrong here ? 
Any suggestions ?

UPDATE : It is firing the event only when I press enter after altering the value in text box. Further, it is showing updated value as "0". How can I make it fetch from the text box instead of my pre defined value ?

Comment: A general comment: this, and pretty much any questions about how these HTML entities work, aren't really Scala.js questions, they're HTML / DOM / JavaScript questions.  Remember that Scala.js is simply a compiler over JavaScript -- it's about the *language*, and the functionality is just ordinary browser functionality -- and on average the Scala.js community aren't focused on DOM functionality.  So I suspect you're likely to get faster answers if you include "html5" and/or "dom" tags as well...

Comment: To the question at hand -- I would only expect it to fire the event after you press enter, since [that's what the documentation indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).  When do you want to be getting this signal, if not when they press Enter?

Comment: And are you sure you're getting the right `id` being passed into your function?  I confess, I'm a bit surprised that the HTML you're showing actually works -- I'm unclear on how that's actually capturing the correct id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input` event instead of `change` if you can ignore IE<=9.

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an  or  element is changed

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Note that for non-text/textarea inputs (e.g. checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.) there are additional browser compatibility caveats, but you can just use `change` event on those. See http://caniuse.com/#search=input for details.

---

I also don't see where the variable `id` is coming from in your code. You should pass the string `"amount"` instead of `id` if that's what you want, like this: `Demo().change("amount")`. That would be quite unreusable, but it should at least work.

If you want the method to be more generic, note that javascript passes an Event object to all event handlers, and it has a `target` key which contains the HTML element on which the event happened (in this case that would be your textarea). You can get then easily get the `value` of that `target`.

If this is confusing, I suggest you try to implement this in JS first, and then translate this into Scala. You don't want to be fighting on both fronts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use one of the onkey handlers. For example:

Note that IIRC, this will also trigger if the user moves around with the arrow keys. So if you really want to only be called if it changes, you'll need to introduce a variable and check:

```
var lastValue: String = ""

@JSExport
def change(id:String): Unit = {
  val newValue = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value")
  if (lastValue != newValue) {
    appendPar(document.body,
      "Text Box value is changed and the new value is : " + newValue)
    lastValue = newValue
  }
}
```